# How to render summary of data item in multiple data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I intend to render summary data (number of data item in each group) after applying custom threshold value against `pos.score`. However, I intend to use `dplyr` functions and `pipe operator` to make this happen. I looked into `SO` to accomplish my goal, whereas using `summarize` functions is suggested. However, I use my own attempt to solve my problem, but can't reach my solution yet. Can anyone point me how to make this happen by using `dplyr` functions or `base R` ? Any way to make this happen easily? Any idea?

Here is minimal reproducible data:

```
Qualified <- list(
        hotan = data.frame( begin=seq(1, by=6, len=45), end=seq(4, by=6, len=45), pos.score=sample(125, 45)),
        aksu = data.frame( begin=seq(3, by=9, len=36), end=seq(6, by=9, len=36), pos.score=sample(84, 36)),
        korla = data.frame( begin=seq(6, by=8, len=52), end=seq(11, by=8, len=52), pos.score=sample(172, 52))
    )
```

Here is my possible attempt by using `dplyr`, but can't work:

```
bind_rows(Qualified, .id = "id") %>%
    mutate(stringency = ifelse(pos.score >= 23,
                               "Stringent", "Weak")) %>% summarise()
```

In my desired solution, number of data item in each group can be reported nicely. Can anyone give me possible idea? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: by group, do you mean `id`? Are you trying to get the number of each `stringency` category in each `id`?

Comment: @Craig after using `mutate` function, I can split them by threshold, then report the summary where number of data item in each group.

Comment: So, your desired output is a data.frame with three columns: `id`, `stringency`, and `count`, right?

Comment: @Craig bingo, that's what I want. Is that possible to use `base R` function to do same things? Can we your solution even better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want counts by group, you need to use `group_by` and then tell `summarize` what summary information you want on the group (in your case, `n()`).

```
bind_rows(Qualified, .id = "id") %>%
  mutate(stringency = ifelse(pos.score >= 23,
                             "Stringent", "Weak")) %>% 
  group_by(id, stringency) %>%
  summarize(n = n())

 #    id stringency     n
 #  aksu  Stringent    25
 #  aksu       Weak    11
 # hotan  Stringent    38
 # hotan       Weak     7
 # korla  Stringent    50
 # korla       Weak     2
```

If you want an actual contingency table, you could assign your mutated data and call `table`

```
df <- bind_rows(Qualified, .id = "id") %>%
  mutate(stringency = ifelse(pos.score >= 23,
                             "Stringent", "Weak"))

table(df$id, df$stringency)

#       Stringent Weak
# aksu         25   11
# hotan        38    7
# korla        50    2
```